# SharePoint 2010 - Multiple RSS feed support in custom RSS viewer webpart

Tags: sharepoint, rss, web-parts, viewer

I have created a custom RSS viewer Web Part by extending the 'RSSAggregatorWebPart' class in Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls. Can I enable multiple feed support in this Web Part through code, by default it has only single feed support.

I am aware about the availabilty of external Web Parts having multiple feed support, but I need to create a create an OOB solution for this.

Guys, have any idea?